# Chamar JButon de um JFrame para outro

Tags: java, swing

Sou iniciante nessa área, e estou com um pequeno probleminha, se poderes me ajudar agradeço..

Tenho dois Frames um é principal (P) e o outro (B) eu chamo através de um botão.
Na tela principal tenho dois botões cadastrar e acessar, quando eu executo a tela principal aparece, o botão cadastrar não aparece (isso é intencional) ficando visível apenas o botão acessar, quando clicar no botão acessar ele chama o frame (B) que por fim tem dois botões, confirmar e cancelar, ao clicar no botão confirmar ele retorna ao frame principal (P), dessa vez com o botão cadastrar visível, mas não tenho ideia de como posso usar o botão cadastrar do frame (P) no frame (B).

Vou enviar o código completo como estou fazendo no netbeans vai ficar um pouco longo..
Essa é a classe Principal que quando clicar no botão Acessar vai abrir a tela do frame B.

```
package javaapplication2;

public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Principal
     */
    public Principal() {
        initComponents();
        JBCadastrar.setVisible(false);


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        JBCadastrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JBAcessar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JBCadastrar.setText("Cadastrar");

        JBAcessar.setText("Acessar");
        JBAcessar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JBAcessarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(147, 147, 147)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(JBCadastrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(JBAcessar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(106, 106, 106)
                .addComponent(JBCadastrar)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(JBAcessar)
                .addContainerGap(110, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(416, 338));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void JBAcessarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String args [] = new String [1];
        FrameB1.main(args);

    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Principal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton JBAcessar;
    private javax.swing.JButton JBCadastrar;
    // End of variables declaration     
}
```

Essa outra é o FrameB1

```
package javaapplication2;

public class FrameB1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form FrameB1
     */
    public FrameB1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        JBConfirmar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JBCancelar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JBConfirmar.setText("Confirmar");
        JBConfirmar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JBConfirmarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JBCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
        JBCancelar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JBCancelarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                .addComponent(JBConfirmar)
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addComponent(JBCancelar)
                .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(JBConfirmar)
                    .addComponent(JBCancelar))
                .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(416, 338));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void JBConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String args [] = new String [1];
        Principal.main(args);
        dispose();
    }                                           

    private void JBCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        dispose();
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameB1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameB1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameB1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameB1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrameB1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton JBCancelar;
    private javax.swing.JButton JBConfirmar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Então, observa que no primeiro frame eu deixei o botão cadastrar invisível
e quando eu clicar em acessar vai chamar a tela do frameB1,e quando eu acionar o botão confirmar vai fechar a janela do frameB1 chamando de volta o frame principal já com o botão cadastrar visível. mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vajamos o que fazem os botões da sua classe `Principal`:

```
    private void JBAcessarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String args [] = new String [1];
        FrameB1.main(args);

    }
```

Vejamos os da sua classe `FrameB1`:

```
    private void JBConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String args [] = new String [1];
        Principal.main(args);
        dispose();
    }        

    private void JBCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();
    }
```

Você tem dois métodos `main` aqui, um em cada classe, o que é errado. Você deveria ter apenas um método `main` e **nunca deveria invocá-lo diretamente**.

O seu erro é se prender na ideia de que só uma tela está ativa por vez e esquecer que isso são objetos. Ao invés disso, separe um arquivo chamado `Main.java`:

```
package javaapplication2;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Principal().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Na sua classe `FrameB1`, troque isso:

```
    public FrameB1() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

Por isso:

```
    private final Principal telaPrincipal;

    public FrameB1(Principal telaPrincipal) {
        this.telaPrincipal = telaPrincipal;
        initComponents();
    }
```

E também isso:

```
    private void JBConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String args [] = new String [1];
        Principal.main(args);
        dispose();
    } 

    private void JBCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();
    }
```

Por isso:

```
    private void JBConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        telaPrincipal.reativar(true);
        dispose();
    } 

    private void JBCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        telaPrincipal.dispose();
        dispose();
    }
```

Na sua classe `Principal`, acrescente esse método:

```
    public void reativar(boolean botaoCadastrarVisivel) {
        setVisible(true);
        JBCadastrar.setVisible(botaoCadastrarVisivel);
    }
```

Troque esse método:

```
    private void JBAcessarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String args [] = new String [1];
        FrameB1.main(args);

    }
```

Por isso:

```
    private void JBAcessarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        FrameB1 fb = new FrameB1(this);
        setVisible(false);
    }
```

E então, você pode retirar o método `main` de ambas as classes `Principal` e `FrameB1`.

Comment: obrigado deu certo.

Comment: @JosueSoares Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não te restar mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no "✅" aqui do lado, o que também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se por outro lado, ainda não estiver satisfeito, deixe um comentário e vamos esclarecer.